# jqgrid currency formatter

Tags: jqgrid

In Jqgrid for currency formatter there is only thousandsSeparator is available but i want lakhsSeparator

```
colModel: [
            {name: 'Code', index: 'Code', width: 55, editable: true, sortable: true },
        { name: 'Ammount', index: 'Ammount', width: 100, editable: true, sortable: false, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { prefix: '($', suffix: ')', thousandsSeparator: ','} },
          ],
```

here in place of thousandsSeparator i want lakhsSeparator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find the question very interesting. I suggest don't implement the [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) plugin. [Here](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/39118647/Globalize) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx) you can find additional information about it.

The usage will be simple. One should define [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#definition_and_parameters) which uses `Globalize.format` and [unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting) which uses `Globalize.parseFloat` functions. For example

```js
formatter: function (v) {
    // uses "c" for currency formatter and "n" for numbers
    return Globalize.format(Number(v), "c");
},
unformat: function (v) {
    return Globalize.parseFloat(v);
}
```

For more comfort I would recommend to define `numberTemplate` and `currencyTemplate` for example like

```js
var numberTemplate = {align: 'right', sorttype: 'number', editable: true,
        searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni']},
        formatter: function (v) {
            return Globalize.format(Number(v), "n");
        },
        unformat: function (v) {
            return Globalize.parseFloat(v);
        }},
    currencyTemplate = {align: 'right', sorttype: 'number', editable: true,
        searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni']},
        formatter: function (v) {
            return Globalize.format(Number(v), "c");
        },
        unformat: function (v) {
            return Globalize.parseFloat(v);
        }};
```

and use there in `colModel` like

```js
{ name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 150, template: currencyTemplate },
{ name: 'age', index: 'age', width: 52, template: numberTemplate },
```

[The demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/lakhsInNumbers.htm) uses "en-IN" locale and display results like on the picture below

[image]

Comment: thanks for the great answer, but again one more info, in this case how would i provide negative currency format like  "-$1.00"

Comment: @Meraj: [The file](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/lib/cultures/globalize.culture.en-IN.js) already contains the information about negative format of currency. For example "Rs. -2,10,98,76,54,321.00". If you find another format for negative currency better you can either modify in your copy of `culture.en-IN.js` `pattern: ["$ -n","$ n"]` to another value or you can use `Globalize.format(Number(v), "n")` instead of `Globalize.format(Number(v), "c")` in custom formatter for currency. You can add "-" or other additional character like you as want.

Comment: @Meraj: Another thing is interesting for me: how the number `"100,000,000,000,000,000"` will be written in your country: as `"1,000,00,00,000,00,00,000"` or as `"1,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,000"`? See the discussion under the answer from Tomasz Pęczek (tpeczek).

Comment: Oleg: we show 10 crore in indian numbering system as 10,00,00,000,00,00,000,  tpeczek solution was spot on in my case.

Comment: @Meraj: Thanks! I'll post the corresponding bug report to the developer of Globalization plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this functionality to currency the formatter. First you would need to modify the built in NumberFormat function. To do this you can run below script after loading jqGrid script files:

```
$.fmatter.util.NumberFormat = function(nData,opts) {
    if(!$.fmatter.isNumber(nData)) {
        nData *= 1;
    }
    if($.fmatter.isNumber(nData)) {
        var bNegative = (nData < 0);
        var sOutput = nData + "";
        var sDecimalSeparator = (opts.decimalSeparator) ? opts.decimalSeparator : ".";
        var nDotIndex;
        if($.fmatter.isNumber(opts.decimalPlaces)) {
            var nDecimalPlaces = opts.decimalPlaces;
            var nDecimal = Math.pow(10, nDecimalPlaces);
            sOutput = Math.round(nData*nDecimal)/nDecimal + "";
            nDotIndex = sOutput.lastIndexOf(".");
            if(nDecimalPlaces > 0) {
                if(nDotIndex < 0) {
                    sOutput += sDecimalSeparator;
                    nDotIndex = sOutput.length-1;
                }
                else if(sDecimalSeparator !== "."){
                    sOutput = sOutput.replace(".",sDecimalSeparator);
                }
                while((sOutput.length - 1 - nDotIndex) < nDecimalPlaces) {
                    sOutput += "0";
                }
            }
        }
        if(opts.thousandsSeparator) {
            var sThousandsSeparator = opts.thousandsSeparator;
            nDotIndex = sOutput.lastIndexOf(sDecimalSeparator);
            nDotIndex = (nDotIndex > -1) ? nDotIndex : sOutput.length;
            var sNewOutput = sOutput.substring(nDotIndex);
            var nCount = -1;
            for (var i=nDotIndex; i>0; i--) {
                nCount++;
                if ((nCount%3 === 0) && (i !== nDotIndex) && (!bNegative || (i > 1))) {
                    sNewOutput = sThousandsSeparator + sNewOutput;
                }
                sNewOutput = sOutput.charAt(i-1) + sNewOutput;
            }
            sOutput = sNewOutput;
        }
        else if(opts.lakhsSeparator) {
            var sLakhsSeparator = opts.lakhsSeparator;
            nDotIndex = sOutput.lastIndexOf(sDecimalSeparator);
            nDotIndex = (nDotIndex > -1) ? nDotIndex : sOutput.length;
            var sNewOutput = sOutput.substring(nDotIndex);
            var nCount = -1;
            var i = nDotIndex;
            while (i > 0) {
                for (var nCount = 0; nCount < 7 && i > 0; nCount++) {
                    sNewOutput = sOutput.charAt(i-1) + sNewOutput;
                    if (((nCount === 2) || (nCount === 4) || (nCount == 6)) && (!bNegative || (i > 1))) {
                        sNewOutput = sLakhsSeparator + sNewOutput;
                    }
                    i--;
                }
            }
            sOutput = sNewOutput;
        }
        sOutput = (opts.prefix) ? opts.prefix + sOutput : sOutput;
        sOutput = (opts.suffix) ? sOutput + opts.suffix : sOutput;
        return sOutput;

    } else {
        return nData;
    }
};
```

Now you can define your formatting options like this:

```
colModel: [
        { name: 'Code', index: 'Code', width: 55, editable: true, sortable: true },
        { name: 'Ammount', index: 'Ammount', width: 100, editable: true, sortable: false, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { prefix: '($', suffix: ')', thousandsSeparator: null, lakhsSeparator: ',' } },
        ...
],
```

That should give you the required result.

Comment: thanks alot its works, with minor change, but if column is editable then we need to append code to unformat.

Comment: @Meraj Yes in case of editing $.unformat should be modified as well

Comment: @tpeczek: How I could understand from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) the Lakh separator should work *together* with Thousands separator. Additionally not only `nCount < 7` is supported. If I understand correct the number `3,210,987,654,321` will be written in India as `32,10,98,76,54,321`. It corresponds `groupSizes: [3,2]` in [globalize.culture.en-IN.js](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/lib/cultures/globalize.culture.en-IN.js) instead of default `groupSizes: [3]` setting in en-US (default setting).

Comment: @tpeczek: I find the easiest way to use Globalize plugin to solve such problems. See my answer for details.

Comment: @Oleg My first approach was similar to yours but then I have read [South Asian numbering system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system) article which introduces Lakh and Crore. According to this article number 3,210,987,654,321 should be written in India as 3,21,098,76,45,321. I think we need an Indian specialist here.

Comment: @tpeczek: It seems that it's one more bug in Globalize plugin. I find funny the usage of mix separators after 2 and 3 position: "1,000,00,00,000" (one thousand crore / one lakh lakh) and "1,000,00,00,000,00,00,000". It seems, one should post one more bug report.

Comment: @Oleg The real question still is what they actually use in India. This subject seems similar to dd.mm.[yy]yy dates in Polish that we once talked about. The standard might be one and the life might be something different.

Comment: @tpeczek: In [the article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system) one can find: "1 billion (100 crore) is written as 1,00,00,00,000", but later in the table one find "100,00,00,000". So I am not really understand whether *both* forms are correct or only one from the table.

Comment: @tpeczek: By the way, could you post pull request about Polish dates (). My pull request to DE and EN in merged [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/b4445e2bac6db36f5affafc799cc93640e46767d). lukasz-schab don't answered till now on my comments [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/299).

Comment: @tpeczek: Thanks! I think that you can make better choice between different date formats currently used Poland as me. :-)