# How to format cultural date in JQGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

JQGrid supports multi-language. That also includes dates. I have formatted most of the date but facing problem in Bulgarian date. As they have date and time like 21.12.2001 r 18:12:30 u. Now, I am facing problem to get that r and u in the date that is getting displayed. Same case is there with Korea.

Input format is 'ISO8601Long' so I need newformat in JQGrid which allows that extra r and u. Else I am getting the format.

I am facing issue while displaying the grid data. Its not edit mode.

Please let me know if any further details needed. You can check details about Bulgaria culture [here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=bulgarian%20style%20guide&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/2/9/a29902cc-41c0-4ceb-a6ed-ba16bc511e15/bul-bgr-StyleGuide.pdf&ei=UMYlUdWTIIj_qwHi6IBo&usg=AFQjCNEW35ruYYXVGl6GKFHy0xko1YDUWQ&bvm=bv.42661473,d.aWc).

Comment: Do you have problem to display date/datetime in jqGrid or in jQuery UI. The example `21.12.2001 r 18:12:30 u` contains datetime instead of date. jQuery UI Datepicker support only **date without time**. Could you describe the problem more exactly? Do you want to display or to edit date/datetime? What is the source format of date? Do you use local datetype of get the data from the server (`datetype: "json"` for example)?

Comment: @Oleg we are having date and time for JQGrid and only date in JQueryUI date picker. 
Current input format for date is ISO long.

Comment: **Do you want to display or to edit date/datetime?** I still don't understand which relation has JQueryUI datepicker to the problem how to display datetime.

Comment: @Oleg Have also edited question. Please let me know if there are any more things I can add for clarification.

Comment: @Oleg we are formatting JQuery UI and JQGrid both. I should remove JQueryUI from here... Wait I ll do that and write in another question. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to repeat that jQuery UI Datepicker support only date without time. Moreover to *display* date with time in jqGrid you don't need jQuery UI Datepicker at all. Do you get the problem during **editing** of jqGrid data?

Comment: @Oleg not in edit mode. But while displaying in grid. We are are showing date in localized format in grid. If you want we can take this to chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is the usage of [Globalize jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jquery/globalize). I modified the demo from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10245286/315935). [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DateWithGlobalize.htm) demonstrate one possible implementation of your requirements.

[image]

I used the following

```
formatter: function (cellvalue) {
    // we don't use time zones information in the code below
    var dMatch = cellvalue.match(new RegExp("([0-9]{4})(-([0-9]{2})(-([0-9]{2})" +
            "(T([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(:([0-9]{2})(.([0-9]+))?)?" +
            "(Z|(([-+])([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})))?)?)?)?")),
        date = new Date(
            Number(dMatch[1] || 0),   // year
            Number(dMatch[3] || 0)-1, // month
            Number(dMatch[5] || 0),   // day
            Number(dMatch[7] || 0),   // hours
            Number(dMatch[8] || 0),   // minutes
            Number(dMatch[10] || 0),  // seconds
            Number(dMatch[12] || 0)
        ); // milliseconds

    return Globalize.format(date, "F");
},
unformat: function (v) {
    return Globalize.parseDate(v);
}
```