# jqGrid - how to focus cell inline editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I found many solutions, but neither doesn't work. I have the latest version 4.7.0.
In example this: [focus cell inline editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536654/how-to-edit-the-selected-cell-on-jqgrid/6538102#6538102).

**My solution is [*code is in coffeescript*]:**

```
ondblClickRow: (rowId, iRow, iCol, e) ->
        if rowId and rowId isnt lastSelectedRowId
            table.jqGrid 'editRow', rowId, true
            $("input, select, textarea", e.target).focus()
            lastSelectedRowId = rowId
```

Doesn't jqGrid have impelemented how to select of cell during inline editing?

Note for Oleg: Please, look at my last comment again [jqgrid (converting datatypes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534767/jqgrid-datatypes-from-server-data-are-converted-all-data-to-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solution, but only for 4.7.0. version.

**coffeescript code, but solution is to see.**

```
ondblClickRow: (rowId, iRow, iCol, e) ->
    if rowId and rowId isnt lastSelectedRowId
        table.jqGrid 'editRow', rowId, {keys:true, focusField: iCol}
        lastSelectedRowId = rowId
```