# jqGrid show an 'edit' icon for in line editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery-grid

I am using the jqGrid with inline editing option. I want to show an edit icon if the cell does not have any values.

So I write a formatter:

```
 function aFormatter(cellvalue, options, row) {
        if(cellvalue == null){          
              return 'you can edit this';
        }else{
            return cellvalue;
        }
 }
```

The `you can edit this` text is displayed, when I click on it an input box is displayed correctly, however the input box as the initial value `you can edit this` ?

How can I fix it?

---

I am using the jqGrid through `struts 2 jquery tags plugin`, which is build on jqGrid version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should define unformatter ([unformat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting)) together with the formatter. For example,

```
formatter: function (cellvalue) {
   if (cellvalue == null) {          
      return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil'></span>";
   } else {
      return cellvalue;
   };
},
unformat: function (cellValue, options, elem) {
    return $(elem).text();
}
```

I'm not sure how you can specify `unformat` in the struts2 grid plugin.

One more way would be defining formatter in the following way

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    /*jslint unparam: true */
    $.extend($.fn.fmatter, {
        yourFormatterName: function (cellValue, options) {
            if (cellvalue == null) {          
                return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil'></span>";
            } else {
                return cellvalue;
            };
        }
    });

    $.extend($.fn.fmatter.yourFormatterName, {
        unformat: function (cellValue, options, elem) {
            return $(elem).text();
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

It will allows you to use `formatter: "yourFormatterName"` (or probably `formatter = "yourFormatterName"` in struts2) in the same way like you can use [standard formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) `"integer"`, `"date"` and other.

Comment: Thanks, as you mentioned struts does not support unformatter and I used extend feature. but I get `$.fn.fmatter is undefined`. Can you please let me know how to fix it ?!

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi: You should include the code **after** jqGrid (after `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`). See [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L50) of jqGrid code which defines `$.fn.fmatter`.

Comment: you are correct but as I am using the jqGrid through struts plugin I could not find where I can put my code. I try to ask it in new question may be struts experts can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will show an "edit" icon instead of "you can edit this" in the grid

```
function aFormatter(cellvalue, options, row) {
   if(cellvalue == null) {          
      return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span>'
   } else {
      return cellvalue;
   }
}
```

Comment: Same issue ... When I click the pencil I see `<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span>` in the input